# What is the most efficient way to iterate between two arrays to find matched values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, foreach

I need to find objects in array by matching array of ids. Array of ids can be longer or equal to length of array of persons. I made it with forEach loop of persons array and inside used includes method to find  matched id but not sure that it is the good approach. Is there a way to optimize searching algorithm?

```
const ids = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3];
const matchedPersons = [];
const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "James"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Alan"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Marry"
  }
];

persons.forEach((person) => {
  if (ids.includes(person.id)) {
    matchedPersons.push(person);
  }
});

console.log(matchedPersons);
```

[codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/iteration-example-wizkz?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: How long does it take now? How fast does it need to be? How large are the arrays typically? It’s one of the arrays sorted on id?

Comment: How long does it take now? How fast does it need to be? - Currently difficult to answer as don't have data to test.
How large are the arrays typically? - Both arrays can store up to 1 million of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with O(1) for the check.

```js
const
    ids = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3],
    persons = [{ id: 1, name: "James" }, { id: 2, name: "Alan" }, { id: 3, name: "Marry" }],
    idsSet = new Set(ids),
    matchedPersons = persons.filter(({ id }) => idsSet.has(id));

console.log(matchedPersons);
```

Comment: matchedPersons = persons.filter(({ id }) => idsSet.has(id)); => How is this O(1)?  The search itself is O(1) but based on the n the iteration has to happen.

Comment: *n* is for the filter.

Comment: So we are on the same on this I guess, just confirming. I am making sure there isn't something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

you better use `filter`. it does exactly what it is meant to do:

```js
const ids = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3];
const persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "James"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Alan"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Marry"
  }
];

const matchedPersons = persons.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id))
console.log(matchedPersons)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get

```
    const ids = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3];
    const matchedPersons = [];
    const persons = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "James"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Alan"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Marry"
    }
    ];

    const personsMap = new Map()
    persons.forEach((person) => {
        personsMap.set(person.id, person)    
    });

    persons.forEach((person) => {
    if (personsMap.has(person.id)) {
        matchedPersons.push(personsMap.get(person.id));
    }
    });

    console.log(matchedPersons);
```